# Failed to build OptiX acceleration structure

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

All day today I have tried to render and basically every 2 times I render I get this error message:

> OPTIX_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE in optixAccelBuild(context, 0, &options,
> &build_input, 1, temp_mem.device_pointer, sizes.tempSizeInBytes,
> out_data.device_pointer, sizes.outputSizeInBytes, &out_handle,
> use_fast_trace_bvh ? &compacted_size_prop : 0, use_fast_trace_bvh ? 1
> : 0)
> (C:\Users\blender\git\blender-vexp\blender.git\intern\cycles\device\optix\device_impl.cpp:1053)

And I have to save, close and reopen and render again. I'm switching between the new stable 3.0 that was just released and the experimental 3.0 that came out a while back that introduced cycles X. Has anyone seen this error before and knows a fix for it?

Now I'm seeing this error also when I'm rendering.

> Invalid handle in cuModuleGetGlobal_v2(&mem, &bytes, cuModule, name)
> (C:\Users\blender\git\blender-vexp\blender.git\intern\cycles\device\cuda\device_impl.cpp:905)